# Hangfire on Elasticache

Tags: amazon-elasticache, hangfire

Is it possible to run [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) on AWS [Elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/)?

Amazon says Elasticache implements Reddis protocols and Hangfire Pro is supports Reddis, so in theory it should be possible. Does anyone know if it's possible in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some customers of mine are using Hangfire.Redis with AWS Elasticache. However, please note that SSL isn't supported by Hangfire.Redis yet.